# detecting vehicles using canny edge detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Is it possible to detect vehicles using canny edge detection. If possible can any one please suggest me the method I would have to use for detecting vehicles from the attached picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OaJK.jpg)

Comment: of course this is possible, but why would you do that? you eliminate so much information by just using an edge image...

Comment: @Piglet I tried background detection algorithm, but its performance  is not good under varying lighting conditions and also when the headlights of vehicle are on. Edge detection performs better under varying lighting conditions and its also eliminates shadows easily. I am using canny edge detection algorithms with some morphological operations on the image.

Comment: @Piglet But I can't detect vehicles from the canny output, I tried findcontours method. Each small box in the image is classified as a new object.

Comment: you'll have to do a bit more than just findcountours... well you could at least pick large, carshaped contours... but as I said, doing that is non-sense. you throw away too much information.

Comment: ok, just one thing, is using canny detection  is not a good way for detecting vehicles? I tired hog descriptor with svm detector, the results were good but the customer do want to use them. Can you please suggest which way I would have to proceed for detecting vehicles in a embedded board.

Comment: please read [ask]. add more info to your post. you cannot expect me to writen extensive answer for just posting 2 lines and some edge image. do your customers know that you have to ask on StackOverflow how to solve their problem? ;)

Comment: good luck and welcome in the world of non-trivial computer vision.